# Code to measure the length of binary numbers in terms of English nomenclature

Tags: python, python-3.x, mathematics

"ONE" and "ZERO".

The basis of this project is in [this 
video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYKn0yUTIU4) -> links to his code can be found in description

In it the speaker asks you to check his math; I wrote my own code and then compared it against his.

It is also in the other GIST i am adding to stack-exchange -> Credit for that code goes to MATT PARKER.

TL;DR This code loops through all the numbers between 0 and the value in "maximum" it calculates how many letters are in the binary form of the word "One" or "Zero" -> 13 (1101) and 18 (10010) are the only two values if spelled with the number of letters it equals its value! In this all variables loop around until they reach either 13 or 18 (explained in video) I counted how many of them go to either 18 (99.9909%) or 13 (the rest).

Please rate my code and how efficient it is: especially as compared to the original code and also how it can be improved!
[Code](https://gist.github.com/miningape/) 
My code is in `main.py` and his is in `binarychain.py`

```
#Creating Variables
Count18 = 0
Count13 = 0
#Change maximum if you don't want to break your computer
maximum = 1000000

#Iterates over each letter and adds to a variable called "letter" for each letter in "one" -> 3 or "Zero" -> 4
def letters(position=0):
    letter = 0
    binary = str('{0:b}'.format(position))

    for ch in binary:
        if ch == '1':
            letter += 3
        if ch == '0':
            letter += 4
    return int(letter)


#Checks if the number reaches 13 or 18
def check(number=0):
    global Count13
    global Count18
    if number == 13:
        Count13 += 1
        return 0
    if number == 18:
        Count18 += 1
        return 0
    if number != 13 or 18:
        return number


running = True
counter = 0
while running:
    checker = check(letters(counter))
    if checker == 0:
        pass
    else:
        #Loops through over and over again until a number reaches either 13 or 18
        while checker != 0:
            checker = check(letters(checker))

    #I could have used a "for" loop but it just wasn't working with this :(
    counter += 1
    if counter > maximum:
        running = False

#Calcualtions for percentage
PerCent18 = (Count18 / maximum)*100
PerCent13 = (Count13 / maximum)*100
print("\nCount 18:", Count18, PerCent18, "Count13:", Count13, PerCent13)

#Just incase it is not being run in an IDE
input()
```

Comment: Code doesn't run.

Comment: Heyo sorry i left out a couple of lines I just added them it should run now!

Answer (score 1):

Just some points:

1. This code here:

   ```
   running = True
   counter = 0
   while running:
       checker = check(letters(counter))
       if checker == 0:
           pass
       else:
           #Loops through over and over again until a number reaches either 13 or 18
           while checker != 0:
               checker = check(letters(checker))

       #I could have used a "for" loop but it just wasn't working with this :(
       counter += 1
       if counter > maximum:
           running = False
   ```

   is a bit repetitive and could be easily simplified. First, let's remove the duplicate `checker = check(letters(counter))` by using a different loop:

   ```
   running = True
   counter = 0
   while running:
       checker = 1 # really any number can be used here
       while checker != 0
           checker = check(letters(counter))
       counter += 1
       if counter > maximum:
           running = False
   ```

   and then we can change the while loop into a for loop:

   ```
   running = True
   counter = 0
   for counter in range(0, maximum + 1):
       checker = 1 # really any number can be used here
       while checker != 0:
           checker = check(letters(counter))
   ```
2. Here:

   ```
   for ch in binary:
       if ch == '1':
           letter += 3
       if ch == '0':
           letter += 4
   ```

   Can't you use an `else`?

   ```
   for ch in binary:
       if ch == '1':
           letter += 3
       else:
           letter += 4
   ```

Comment: In your (1) the edits change the meaning of the code — in the post the first call was `check(letters(counter))` but subsequent calls were `check(letters(checker))` whereas all your calls are the same. So I think this answer needs a bit more work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code in my opinion is more complex than it should be, because the function that checks if a number ends in \$18\$ could just return a boolean because a number either ends in \$18\$ or \$13\$, and this is already a known fact when writing the program.

Therefore we do not need any global variables.

I wrote the function in recursive form because that way memoization could be used. Memoization is basically recording the result of a function when given a certain input, so that when the same input is given again the program can just look up the answer instead of recalculating it.

Memoization is easiest to use when the function is written recursively, hance I wrote the function recursively.

Both memoization and writing the function to be a boolean did not speed up the program, memoization in fact slowed it down, writing the function as a boolean slowed it a tiny bit.

Memoization did not help because the calculation is so simple that it actually is faster to compute it again every time then to fetch it from a dictionary (hashtable) in memory. Still it seemed worth trying.

```
def ends_in_18(number):
    if number == 18:
        return True
    if number == 13:
        return False
    return ends_in_18(letters(number))
```

This function is used like this:

```
eighteen = (sum(ends_in_18(n) for n in xrange(1, MAXIMUM)))
thirteen = MAXIMUM - eighteen
print("eighteen", eighteen, eighteen / float(MAXIMUM), "thirteen", thirteen, thirteen / float(MAXIMUM))
```

`sum` counts the number of times the function is `True` because True is counted as \$1\$ (and `False` as \$0\$).

I think this change is still worth making because the ~ 10% efficency decrease is worth the simplicity increase.

Another change that struck my mind was re-writing `letters` as `sum` over a generator expression, that slowed the program a lot (~ 50%), so I show that change just for your curiosity and because it is simpler and shorter to write:

```
def letters(position):
    return sum(4 if ch == '0' else 3 for ch in str('{0:b}'.format(position)))
```

---

The best way to improve the runtime of your code is to port it to Python 2 (very easy, just add `float` where division is performed) and to run it with `pypy`, for example with `maximum = 100000`

```
$> time pypy bleno.py
('\nCount 18:', 99904, 0, 'Count13:', 97, 0)

real    0m0.324s
user    0m0.296s
sys 0m0.024s

$> time python bleno.py
('\nCount 18:', 99904, 0, 'Count13:', 97, 0)

real    0m1.536s
user    0m1.520s
sys 0m0.012s
```

The speed-up really is significant. Running `MAXIMUM = 100000000` (\$10**8\$) took about 5 minutes with pypy, I did not even dare trying with regular cPython.

---

As a final note, please make constants `ALL_UPPERCASE` so that the PEP8 convention is respected.